# How to register a single-tenant SPA on Azure AD?

Tags: angular, azure, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I created a new Angular project and setup MSAL (`@azure/msal-angular`).

When I go to a MsalGuarded route it correctly redirects me to sign in. But, after providing my credentials  I get an error saying:

```
We're unable to complete your request
unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
```

On Azure portal, I registered a SPA, single tenant, with the redirect URI http://localhost:4200, as I don't want it enabled for consumers.

I tried enabling/disabling implicit grant but it doesn't help (and it shouldn't be enabled for OAuth2/OpenID Connect anyways)

My question is: is it possible to register a **single tenant SPA**? Or does single tenant only work with private clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to public the spa application to other accounts. If you use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/`, it means it accepts any account, then you need to select **my application** and then transfer go to the **Authentication** tab and after that under **Supported account types**, selected **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)** .

If you want to restrict the spa application to this tenant, that is, not public it to other tenants, you can try `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id/` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/` log in.

Comment: Setting the `authority` option to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant id/` worked